# jqgrid incorrect select drop down option values in edit box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, edit

I am using form edit. There are two select boxes in the form. One select box is the country, another select box is the state. The state select box depends on the country selected and will be populated dynamically. For example:

Country:

> US (option value=1)
>  UK (option value=2)

State for US:

> Alabama (option value=1)
>  California (option value=2)
>  Florida
>   (option value=3)
>  Hawaii (option value=4)

State for UK:

> London (option value=5)
>  Oxford (option value=6)

As you can see above the id of state for uk starts with 5. When I edit a record which contained `Country id=2 (UK)` and `State id=6 (Oxford)`, the edit form will shows correctly - Country is UK and State is Oxford. But if you drop down the state select box the option text is correct (it shows London Oxford) but the option value will starts from 0. What should be correct is that the option value should starts from 5.

If you select and change the country drop down box to US then change back again to UK, the option value will be populated correct (starts from 5).

My question is, how can we populate the select box for the state with the correct option value based on the country in edit box when the edit form loads?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The answer on your question depend a little from the source where you receive the information about displayed under "State for US" and "State for UK". The are two possibilities supported by jqGrid: 1) the usage of `value` parameter of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) 2) the usage of `dataUrl` and `buildSelect` parameter of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). The first way is the best one in case of local editing or in the case if the list of possible options is static. The second choose will be used in the case, that the information about states, countries and the states of some country will be get per AJAX request from the database. I describe the solution on the example the usage of `value` parameter to have no dependencies to the server components. The most parts on the implementation are the same in case of the usage of `dataUrl` and `buildSelect`.

I made [the live example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects1.htm) which demonstrate what you need.

The main problem is that the `value` of the `editoptions` are used **only once** at the time on the initialization. Inside of [dataInit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) function one can overwrite the `value`, but after the changing of the value in the first select/drop-down box with countries the second select/drop-down box with states must be rebuild manually. To do so one have to understand, that the select HTML element has id constructed from row id '_' and the column name: rowId + "_State". Moreover it is important, that the the `value` of the `editoptions` must be reset to the initial value, so that any state id can be decoded to the state name.

Here is the code from [the example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects1.htm):

```
var countries = { '1': 'US', '2': 'UK' };
var states = { '1': 'Alabama', '2': 'California', '3': 'Florida', '4': 'Hawaii', '5': 'London', '6': 'Oxford' };
var statesOfCountry = {
    1: { '1': 'Alabama', '2': 'California', '3': 'Florida', '4': 'Hawaii' },
    2: { '5': 'London', '6': 'Oxford' }
};
var mydata = [
    { id: '0', Country: '1', State: '1', Name: "Louise Fletcher" },
    { id: '1', Country: '1', State: '3', Name: "Jim Morrison" },
    { id: '2', Country: '2', State: '5', Name: "Sherlock Holmes" },
    { id: '3', Country: '2', State: '6', Name: "Oscar Wilde" }
];

var lastSel = -1;
var grid = jQuery("#list");
var resetStatesValues = function () {
    grid.setColProp('State', { editoptions: { value: states} });
};
grid.jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: 'local',
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Name', width: 200 },
        { name: 'Country', width: 100, editable: true, formatter: 'select',
            edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                value: countries,
                dataInit: function (elem) {
                    var v = $(elem).val();
                    // to have short list of options which corresponds to the country
                    // from the row we have to change temporary the column property
                    grid.setColProp('State', { editoptions: { value: statesOfCountry[v]} });
                },
                dataEvents: [
                    {
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function(e) {
                            // To be able to save the results of the current selection
                            // the value of the column property must contain at least
                            // the current selected 'State'. So we have to reset
                            // the column property to the following
                            //grid.setColProp('State', { editoptions:{value: statesOfCountry[v]} });
                            //grid.setColProp('State', { editoptions: { value: states} });
                            resetStatesValues();

                            // build 'State' options based on the selected 'Country' value
                            var v = parseInt($(e.target).val(), 10);
                            var sc = statesOfCountry[v];
                            var newOptions = '';
                            for (var stateId in sc) {
                                if (sc.hasOwnProperty(stateId)) {
                                    newOptions += '<option role="option" value="' +
                                                  stateId + '">' +
                                                  states[stateId] + '</option>';
                                }
                            }

                            // populate the new
                            if ($(e.target).is('.FormElement')) {
                                // form editing
                                var form = $(e.target).closest('form.FormGrid');
                                $("select#State.FormElement", form[0]).html(newOptions);
                            } else {
                                // inline editing
                                var row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                                var rowId = row.attr('id');
                                $("select#" + rowId + "_State", row[0]).html(newOptions);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'State', width: 100, editable: true, formatter: 'select',
            edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: states }
        }
    ],
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (id && id !== lastSel) {
            if (lastSel != -1) {
                resetStatesValues();
                grid.restoreRow(lastSel);
            }
            lastSel = id;
        }
    },
    ondblClickRow: function (id, ri, ci) {
        if (id && id !== lastSel) {
            grid.restoreRow(lastSel);
            lastSel = id;
        }
        resetStatesValues();
        grid.editRow(id, true, null, null, 'clientArray', null,
                        function (rowid, response) {  // aftersavefunc
                            grid.setColProp('State', { editoptions: { value: states} });
                        });
        return;
    },
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    sortname: 'Name',
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    pager: '#pager',
    caption: "Demonstrate dependend select/dropdown lists (edit on double-click)"
}).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', 
          { edit: true, add: true, del: false, search: false, refresh: false },
          { // edit options
              recreateForm:true,
              onClose:function() {
                  resetStatesValues();
              }
          },
          { // add options
              recreateForm:true,
              onClose:function() {
                  resetStatesValues();
              }
          });
```

**UPDATED**: I updated the code above to make it working with in case of form editing too. You can see it live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects2.htm). Because jqGrid not support local editing for form editing I could not tested the code. Nevertheless I hope that I made the most of required changes.

**UPDATED 2**: I extended the above code to support

1. Inline editing, Form editing, Searching Toolbar and Advanced Searching
2. The previous or next navigation buttons in the editing form
3. Improving keyboard support in selects (problem with refreshing dependent select in some browsers are fixed)

The new version of the demo is [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditWithDependendSelects2.htm). The modified code of the demo you find below:

```
var countries = { '1': 'US', '2': 'UK' },
    //allCountries = {'': 'All', '1': 'US', '2': 'UK'},
    // we use string form of allCountries to have control on the order of items
    allCountries = ':All;1:US;2:UK',
    states = { '1': 'Alabama', '2': 'California', '3': 'Florida', '4': 'Hawaii', '5': 'London', '6': 'Oxford' },
    allStates = ':All;1:Alabama;2:California;3:Florida;4:Hawaii;5:London;6:Oxford',
    statesOfUS = { '1': 'Alabama', '2': 'California', '3': 'Florida', '4': 'Hawaii' },
    statesOfUK = { '5': 'London', '6': 'Oxford' },
    // the next maps contries by ids to states
    statesOfCountry = { '': states, '1': statesOfUS, '2': statesOfUK },
    mydata = [
        { id: '0', country: '1', state: '1', name: "Louise Fletcher" },
        { id: '1', country: '1', state: '3', name: "Jim Morrison" },
        { id: '2', country: '2', state: '5', name: "Sherlock Holmes" },
        { id: '3', country: '2', state: '6', name: "Oscar Wilde" }
    ],
    lastSel = -1,
    grid = $("#list"),
    removeAllOption = function (elem) {
        if (typeof elem === "object" && typeof elem.id === "string" && elem.id.substr(0, 3) !== "gs_") {
            // in the searching bar
            $(elem).find('option[value=""]').remove();
        }
    },
    resetStatesValues = function () {
        // set 'value' property of the editoptions to initial state
        grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'state', { editoptions: { value: states} });
    },
    setStateValues = function (countryId) {
        // to have short list of options which corresponds to the country
        // from the row we have to change temporary the column property
        grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'state', { editoptions: { value: statesOfCountry[countryId]} });
    },
    changeStateSelect = function (countryId, countryElem) {
        // build 'state' options based on the selected 'country' value
        var stateId, stateSelect, parentWidth, $row,
            $countryElem = $(countryElem),
            sc = statesOfCountry[countryId],
            isInSearchToolbar = $countryElem.parent().parent().parent().hasClass('ui-search-toolbar'),
                              //$(countryElem).parent().parent().hasClass('ui-th-column')
            newOptions = isInSearchToolbar ? '<option value="">All</option>' : '';

        for (stateId in sc) {
            if (sc.hasOwnProperty(stateId)) {
                newOptions += '<option role="option" value="' + stateId + '">' +
                    states[stateId] + '</option>';
            }
        }

        setStateValues(countryId);

        // populate the subset of contries
        if (isInSearchToolbar) {
            // searching toolbar
            $row = $countryElem.closest('tr.ui-search-toolbar');
            stateSelect = $row.find(">th.ui-th-column select#gs_state");
            parentWidth = stateSelect.parent().width();
            stateSelect.html(newOptions).css({width: parentWidth});
        } else if ($countryElem.is('.FormElement')) {
            // form editing
            $countryElem.closest('form.FormGrid').find("select#state.FormElement").html(newOptions);
        } else {
            // inline editing
            $row = $countryElem.closest('tr.jqgrow');
            $("select#" + $.jgrid.jqID($row.attr('id')) + "_state").html(newOptions);
        }
    },
    editGridRowOptions = {
        recreateForm: true,
        onclickPgButtons: function (whichButton, $form, rowid) {
            var $row = $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid)), countryId;
            if (whichButton === 'next') {
                $row = $row.next();
            } else if (whichButton === 'prev') {
                $row = $row.prev();
            }
            if ($row.length > 0) {
                countryId = grid.jqGrid('getCell', $row.attr('id'), 'country');
                changeStateSelect(countryId, $("#country")[0]);
            }
        },
        onClose: function () {
            resetStatesValues();
        }
    };

grid.jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: 'local',
    colModel: [
        { name: 'name', width: 200, editable: true },
        { name: 'country', width: 100, editable: true, formatter: 'select', stype: 'select', edittype: 'select',
            searchoptions: {
                value: allCountries,
                dataInit: function (elem) { removeAllOption(elem); },
                dataEvents: [
                    { type: 'change', fn: function (e) { changeStateSelect($(e.target).val(), e.target); } },
                    { type: 'keyup', fn: function (e) { $(e.target).trigger('change'); } }
                ]
            },
            editoptions: {
                value: countries,
                dataInit: function (elem) { setStateValues($(elem).val()); },
                dataEvents: [
                    { type: 'change', fn: function (e) { changeStateSelect($(e.target).val(), e.target); } },
                    { type: 'keyup', fn: function (e) { $(e.target).trigger('change'); } }
                ]
            }},
        { name: 'state', width: 100, formatter: 'select', stype: 'select',
            editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: states },
            searchoptions: { value: allStates, dataInit: function (elem) { removeAllOption(elem); } } }
    ],
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (id && id !== lastSel) {
            if (lastSel !== -1) {
                $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
                resetStatesValues();
            }
            lastSel = id;
        }
    },
    ondblClickRow: function (id) {
        if (id && id !== lastSel) {
            $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
            lastSel = id;
        }
        resetStatesValues();
        $(this).jqGrid('editRow', id, {
            keys: true,
            aftersavefunc: function () {
                resetStatesValues();
            },
            afterrestorefunc: function () {
                resetStatesValues();
            }
        });
        return;
    },
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    sortname: 'name',
    ignoreCase: true,
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    pager: '#pager',
    caption: "Demonstrate dependend select/dropdown lists (inline editing on double-click)"
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { del: false }, editGridRowOptions, editGridRowOptions);
grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch : "cn"});
```

**UPDATED 3**: The last version of the code of the demo you will find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditWithDependendSelects2_.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually already got the on change select country and populate the state correctly. There is no problem there. Your example shows line editing but I am having problem with form edit (select highlight a row and click on Pencil icon). The issue I am having is that when the form shows up, the selected country and selected state on the select box is display correctly. The drop down box for the state also populated correctly. The issue is that the value of the option value starts from 0 which is wrong.

Comment: By the way, I am using the usage of value parameter of editoptions method and my codes are the same as the way you done as the codes that you included above

Comment: @Alex: I updated my code example to make it working also in case of "form editing". Next time please, if you have already a working or half-working solution, you should post it as a part of your question. It will save the time of people who answer on your question.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Sorry I didn't include my codes. I will remember to do that next time. Your codes works perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Oleg: what i need to change if i want the dropdown to be populated from a database?? 
plus i want to show two field, ID and NAME (i.e. 1 and Alabama both), any suggestions.. thanks

Comment: @indyaah: The changes will be large enough. You can use `dataUrl` and optionally `buildSelect` instead of `value`. The implementation can has many aspects. For example it could be required to set `ajaxSelectOptions: { cache: false }` additionally or set `Cache-Control: private, max-age=0` in the HTTP header (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7877286/315935))

Comment: Dependency select a little bit complicated. Do we have easiest way to manage it? Especially, I mean form editing and dynamically populate select when other is changed.(For example update regions when country changed)

Comment: @Yara: The code is commented. If you need solution which work only in case of form editing you can reduce the code below the comment "// populate the subset of countries". Really simple can be the implementation of depended selects only if the main code of jqGrid will be expended.

Comment: Has anyone seen an example somewhere on the web, where this is done using dataUrl, loading data from a database instead?

Comment: @kaze, have you found the example with loading data from database? I am trying to find the solution for this almost few weeks, but till now without big success...

Comment: @Oleg, in the new version of your demo the inline editing seems to does not work...Please check this.

Comment: @Anatoliy: You are right! Thanks! I will examine the demo in the evening.

Comment: @Anatoliy: It was simple typing error. It should be used `"_state"` instead of `"_tate"` in the code after `// inline editing`. The demo is fixed now.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, Can you make this dropdownlist for  dynamic content populate

Comment: @Sajith: Sorry, but I would need to invest many time to do this. Moreover I think that the best way would be modification of jqGrid code so that one could **refresh** (**rebuild**) content of select. So one would need just to modify `editoptions` of dependent column and trigger such rebuilding. Such behavior would be practically the same in case of static (`value`) or dynamic (`dataUrl`, `data` with function etc). In any way one need invest some time for implementation, but I have to work for my customers now...

Comment: @Oleg I have some columns as 'select'. The data returned of those columns have values as well as display values. Select boxes are loaded dynamically. How can I show display values on grid rows? While saving the record it should send the actual values instead of display values. I am not able to find a good way to handle this.

Comment: @bluetech: I hope that I understand you correctly. In the case you need just add `formatter: "select"` to the column definition. If it will not help then you should describe the problem more detailed. Posting new question would be the best in the case if `formatter: "select"` would not help along.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg - here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582801/how-to-jqgrid-dependent-select-box-display-values-in-rows

Comment: Hi @Oleg does you answer still applies to latest version of free jqgrid as I am also looking for cascading dropdowns in edit form fields.