# Change value of drop down of specific row in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have created at a table using jqGrid. In that I have a comboBox. I want the values of the combobox such that It is not used in the previous row.

But, once my first row displayed, then I am unable to change the values of comboBoc in the second row.

Ex: In my combobox, there are three values .. `one`, `two`, `three`. I have selected value "two" in the first row. Then the combo box of the second must have two values: `one` and `three`.

I have tried the following code:

```
$("#listData").setColProp('denomination',
    {editoptions:{value:getDenominationList('addOperation').toString()}});
```

Here:

`getDenominationList('addOperation')` will return a String `"1:one;3:three"`

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand correct your question and you want to change the `value` parameter of `editoptions` every time depend on the current row id or other grid contain. You can do this inside your custom `dataInit` event handler (see [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions)):

```
dataInit: function (elem) {
    var v = $(elem).val();
    var rowId = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow').attr('id');
    var newValue = getDenominationList('addOperation').toString();
    $("#listData").setColProp('denomination', { editoptions: { value:newValue} });
}
```

The function `getDenominationList` used in your question don't has the `rowid` parameter which you probably will need. To simplified it I included in the code above the line which show how the `id` of the row can be got.

I recommend you to look inside the [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469650/jqgrid-incorrect-select-drop-down-option-values-in-edit-box/4480184#4480184) which I recently answered. It showed how the initial values of `value` property can be **reseted** in case of [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing). It you use [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) you should do this inside of [onClose](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event handler. Moreover in case of [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) you must use [recreateForm:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) which will force that `dataInit` event handler will be called not once, but on every row editing.

Comment: Sorry, but I am currently in business trip and I am very busy with other projects. So I have no time to prepare new examples.