# How to use focusout on text field in modal form from jqGrid custom_func?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-validate, modal-dialog, jquery-focusout

In colModel I have one `custom_func: myFunc()` which tests whether an integer value entered into the text field of the jqGrid native Add or Edit modal form is not already in use in the handful of rows visible in the grid where `loadonce:true` is set in the options. The way it is the `custom_func:` is not executed until the modal form Submit button is clicked but I'd like to have the modal form text field tested when it is focusout (or blur?). Is there a way to do this? I've tried to do it as showing below in the `afterShowForm:` option and it kind of works but the error message and halting is not the same as when the Submit button is clicked, is there a way to do focusout/blur from `custom_func: myFunc()`?

The following shows colModel snippet followed by the custom function followed by my attempt to use focusout in `afterFormShow: function()` of the Add modal form.

```
//colModel
...},
{name: 'ezyid', index: 'ezyid', width: 60, align: "center", editable: true,
        formoptions: { rowpos: 1,
            colpos: 1,
            label: "Ezy ID",
            elmprefix: "(*) " 
            },
editrules: {
            custom: true,
            custom_func: chkDuplicateEzyids, //custom function
            required: true
            }
        },
```

The colModel custom function:

```
function chkDuplicateEzyids(value, colname) {

var isFound = false;

var rows = grid.jqGrid('getRowData');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

    var row = rows[i];

    if (value == row.ezyid && value != '') { isFound = true };

}

if(isFound){

    return [false, "This Ezy ID is in use, please enter another or press Cancel."];

} else {

    return [true, ""];

}

}
```

My less than ideal attempt to use the custom function accessed from the `afterShowForm:` option of the Add modal form options (would be similar use in Edit if it had to be done this way):

```
addSettings = {
recreateForm: true,
jqModal: false,
reloadAfterSubmit: false,
closeOnEscape: true,
closeAfterAdd: true,
afterShowForm: function ($form) {
    var form = $form.parent()[0];

    $("#ezyid", form).blur(function () { //or focusout() if better

        var resp = chkDuplicateEzyids($(this).val(), 'Ezy ID');

        if (!resp[0]) {
            $("#FormError", form).show();
            $(".ui-state-error", form).html(resp[1]);
        }
    });

    $("#lui_" + grid[0].id).hide();
},
onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
},
```

To summarize, I'd like to use focusout (or blur) to immediately test the text field value rather than having to enter in all other values of the form to get to the Submit button only to find the value is already in use. This seems a common practice but I cannot figure it out in this context. Many TIA.

( some code snippet(s) reused with by approval and with appreciation to stackoverflow user @Oleg )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [dataEvents](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules&s%5B%5D=multiple#editoptions) to bind any event handler (like [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) which is a little better as `blur`) to the corresponding input control. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247138/jqgrid-change-cell-value-and-stay-in-edit-mode/5257794#5257794) for an example.

One more remark. The `'ezyid'` column seems to have **unique** values. So you can consider to use `key: true` in the column. In the case the ids for the grid rows (for the `<tr>` elements of the `<table>`) will be used with the values from the column. In the case the `chkDuplicateEzyids` function can be reduced to the `if ($('#' + value).length > 0) {/*duplicate are found*/}` or to the `if ($('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(value)).length > 0) {/*duplicate are found*/}` if you would allows to use [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in the id. The only thing which you need to implement hiding of the `'ezyid'` column in the Edit dialog (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405029/jqgrid-disable-form-fields-when-editing/3405961#3405961) for details) and show it only in the "Add" form.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Oleg, works just the way I want now. Some of these client-side concepts involve some steep learning curves and I like how you leave just enough gray area in your answers to have to dig a little and when it's figured out the understanding is better. I've developed Classic ASP and .NET server side apps for quite awhile but still have to stop and recalibrate the thinking for this client UI scripting. I'll post the code that fixed my problem tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jerry Of Perth: I am glad that I could help you. You are welcome! I had the same problems 3 year ago as I started to use JavaScript after the usage of more "classical" languages like C/C++ and C#. So I understand good your problems.