# editRow not working after setCell in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using setCell to set the value of a cell , and after that enabling the cell for editing

```
grid.jqGrid('setCell','1','Valid','5');
grid.jqGrid('editRow','1', false);
```

but the result ist i cant click any longer on the cell ?

[image: no longer editeble]

after calling serCell the cell cant by any longer editable.

How can i make this cell again editable ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that `setCell` does not work properly when the cell is in edit mode. See this question for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247138/jqgrid-change-cell-value-and-stay-in-edit-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the comment i find the solution

instead to set the column value like this

`grid.jqGrid('setCell','1','Valid','5');`

you need to set it like this :
`$('#1_Valid').val('5');`