# JQGrid: How can I refresh a dropdown after edit?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In my application, I use JQGrid for loading some contacts data, and when I edit/add an entry I select the contact's name from database and then update/add contact.

My problem is that, when I click the submit button I want to refresh the dropdown and the data that has been already entered to dispaear from dropdown list.

My code:

for colModel:

```
{ name: 'OwnerEmail', index: 'OwnerEmail', width: 200, align: "center", sortable: true, sorttype: 'text', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { value: ownersList} },
```

I populate the dropdown on select row (that when I select a row, the dropdown will be refreshed)

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
                var advOwners = $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {},
                    url: 'MyWebService.asmx/GetOwners',
                    async: false,
                    error: function () {
                        alert('An error has occured retrieving Owners!');
                    }
                }).responseXML;

                var aux = advOwners.getElementsByTagName("string");
                ownersList = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
                    ownersList += aux[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ':' + aux[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '; ';
                }
                ownersList = ownersList.substring(0, ownersList.length - 2);

                jQuery("#GridView").setColProp('OwnerEmail', { editoptions: { value: ownersList} });
             }
```

But when I enter the edit/add form again, the dropdown it's not refreshed, it has the items that has been loaded in the first place.

Any help?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it will be better if you would use `dataUrl` property of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions) instead of usage `value` property. In the case you will don't need to use synchronous Ajax call inside of `onSelectRow` to get the select data manually. If the data will be needed the corresponding call will do jqGrid for you.

The URL from `dataUrl` should return HTML fragment for `<select>` element including all `<options>`. So you can convert any other response from `dataUrl` to the required format implementing the corresponding `buildSelect` callback function.

On your place I would prefer to return JSON data from the 'MyWebService.asmx/GetOwners' URL instead of XML data which you currently do. In the simplest case it could be web method like

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> GetSelectData() {
    return new List<string> {
        "User1", "User2", "User3", "User4"
    };
}
```

If you would use HTTP GET instead of HTTP POST you should prevent usage of data from the cache by setting `Cache-Control: private, max-age=0` in the HTTP header. the corresponding code will be

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> GetSelectData() {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge (new TimeSpan(0));
    return new List<string> {
        "User1", "User2", "User3", "User4"
    };
}
```

Per default jqGrid use `dataType: "html"` in the corresponding Ajax call (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.common.js#L345)). To change the behavior to `dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json"` you should use additionally the `ajaxSelectOptions` parameter of jqGrid as

```
ajaxSelectOptions: { contentType: "application/json", dataType: 'json' },
```

or as

```
ajaxSelectOptions: {
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST"
},
```

if you will use HTTP POST which is default for ASMX web services.

The corresponding setting for the column in the `colModel` will be

```
edittype: 'select', editable: true,
editoptions: {
    dataUrl: '/MyWebService.asmx/GetSelectData',
    buildSelect: buildSelectFromJson
}
```

where

```
var buildSelectFromJson = function (data) {
        var html = '<select>', d = data.d, length = d.length, i = 0, item;
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            item = d[i];
            html += '<option value=' + item + '>' + item + '</option>';
        }
        html += '</select>';
        return html;
    };
```

Be careful that the above code use `data.d` which is required in case of ASMX web services. If you would migrate to ASP.NET MVC or to WCF you will need remove the usage of `d` property and use `data` directly.

**UPDATED**: [Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridASMXdataUrl.zip) you can download the VS2010 demo project which implements what I wrote above.

Comment: I've followed your opinion and changed the code, but it never enters the GetSelectData web method..

Comment: @Jeff Norman: If you would help I can upload a demo project which I used to verify my suggestions.

Comment: @JeffNorman: [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridASMXdataUrl.zip) you can find the demo VS2010 project which implement `dataUrl` in the form like I described. The demo don't implement the editing itself, so the data can't be saved after end of the editing.