# How to add Select Box In Edit Row in Jqgid?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I am use jqgrid. I want to add record inline navigation
Now I want add select Box in Rows Field.
how it possible?
I am get Data from Database using Ajax and I want to add these data in Select Box.
How its Possible?
Please Help
My Ajax Code

```
$.ajax({
 url : "getAllWards.html",
 data : "&time=" + new Date().getTime(),
 type : 'GET',
 dataType : 'JSON',
 success : function(data) {}
});
```

my JqGrid Code

```
jQuery("#room").jqGrid(
{
 mtype : 'GET',
 url : "listAllRooms.html",
 colModel : [ .....,
 ,{
name : 'wardType',
index : 'wardType',
width : 150,
edittype: "select",
editrules: { required: true },
editoptions: { size: 71},
editable:true,
}],
```

Comment: @Oleg please help How add Dynamic Data in select box

Comment: @oleg Above problem is solve jQuery("#room").jqGrid('setColProp','wardType', { editoptions: { value: wardTypes} });
where wardTypes is variable get from the database using Ajax 
now i want to add set ward id to its Optionvalue and wardType to option.SO how its?

Comment: I have seen the second comment only now after posting the answer. So 1) if you want send me notification you should write comment with "@Oleg" in some my *previous answer*. If you post new question "@Oleg" can't be resolved. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=oleg) for different users with the same name.

Comment: It seems to me that you should better use `dataUrl` with probably `buildSelect` for formatting. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4102155/315935) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7877286/315935).

Answer (score 1):

If you want use `edittype: "select"` you should specify `value` or `dataUrl` property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions).

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/InlineEditingInlineNav.htm) provide as example.

**UPDATED**: It seems to me that you should better use `dataUrl` with probably `buildSelect` for formatting. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4102155/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877286/315935).

Comment: in dataUrl code 
Url = ? is My Ajax Url and GetDestinationList= ?

Comment: @AshuMehta: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. If you use ASP.NET you should just read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7877286/315935) or download the demo project which I provide.

Comment: I have wardId and wardName two field and these two field to set in <select> Tag value and option

Comment: by Using Ajax I get Id and type

Comment: now these 'id' set in jqgrid select box value and 'Type' set in <select>'Type'</select>

Comment: i Want like these 
jQuery("#room").jqGrid('setColProp','Ward_Type', { editoptions: {value:'WardId:wardTypes'});
but it gives Error

Comment: @AshuMehta: You can return from the server (from the URL specified by `dataURL`) the HTML fragment `<select value='123'>'Type 1'</select><select value='456'>'Type 2'</select>...`. Alternatively you can build the HTML fragment inside of `buildSelect` from the data in another format. For example you can return from `dataUrl` JSON `[{"id":"123","name":"Type 1"},{"id":"456","name":"Type 2"}]` and convert the object in above HTML fragment inside of `buildSelect`.

Comment: @AshuMehta: I personally prefer to post to jqGrid only the texts of `<select>` options and use `value` the same as the text of the option. The conversion of texts to the corresponding id back I did on the server. It makes filling of grid and editing more easy and jqGrid need "know" less information about the database implementation.

Comment: By using Json I GOt Data Like {"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","General",null]},{"id":"2","cell":["2","AC","AC"]},{"id":"3","cell":["3","Special-S","special-s"]},{"id":"4","cell":["4","OT","ot"]},{"id":"5","cell":["5","NICU","nicu"]}]} And How to use BuildSelect And HTML fragment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18622/discussion-between-ashumehta-and-oleg)