# jqGrid Filter Toolbar and Date and Select filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, filtering

I have a jqGrid:

```
$('#jqgFileInfoList').jqGrid({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetFiles", "File")',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Interface', 'Amount', 'Type', 'Created', 'Status'],
    colModel: [
        { jsonmap: 'Id', name: 'Id', formatter: 'integer', align: 'right', hidden: true },
        { jsonmap: 'Name', name: 'Name', align: 'right', hidden: true },
        { jsonmap: 'InterfaceName', name: 'InterfaceName', align: 'left', width: '100%', sorttype: 'text', frozen: true, search: true },
        { jsonmap: 'Amount', name: 'Amount', formatter: 'currency', align: 'right', width: '100%', sorttype: 'number', search: true },
        { jsonmap: 'Type', name: 'Type', align: 'right', width: '100%', sorttype: 'text', search: true },
        { jsonmap: 'RunDate', name: 'RunDate', formatter: 'date', align: 'right', width: '100%', sorttype: 'date', search: true },
        { jsonmap: 'Status', name: 'Status', align: 'right', width: '100%', sorttype: 'text', formatter: formatStatus, search: true }
    ],
    sortname: 'RunDate',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    pager: $('#jqgPagerFileInfoList'),
    rowNum: 5,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: '100%',
    autowidth: true,
    refresh: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: "rows"
    },
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'jqGridAltRow',
    loadComplete: function () {
        $("tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass('jqGridAltRow');
    }
});

$('#jqgFileInfoList').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOnEnter: false, enableClear: true, stringResult: true });
```

Filtering is working, except for a couple columns I want to modify.

The Created/RunDate column I would like to filter a range somehow.  Picking a single date is not useful.

The Interface, Type and Status columns I would like to use drop downs.  What's the best way to do this?

I find the jqGrid documentation VERY difficult to follow, there are just so many options.  It took me an hour to figure out that I needed `stringResult: true` to get my filter options into the `GridSettings.Where` property in the controller.

And if it matters, it's a .Net 4.0, MVC app.

***EDIT***: **Bonus Question**: How do I make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that [the official documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs) can be used only more as reference and not as the introduction for developer who start to use it, especially not for .NET developer.

To your questions:

1) There are no simple way to implement searching by range of dates. One could make some tricks like the trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953934/315935). The usage of `beforeSearch` callback of `filterToolbar` or `onSearch` callback of advanced searching allows to "pre-process" searching filter before it will be applied, but all together is very tricky. In case of usage server side sorting you can implement the same on the server side directly.

2) There are many ways to implement drop downs in jqGrid. The main alternatives are the usage of `value` or `dataUrl` properties of [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options). The best choice depend on your exact requirements.

The usage of `value` is very practical if the column have some small set of values which are more static as dynamic. For example if you use `formatter: "checkbox"` in the grid to display boolean data as checkboxes you would like sure to use drop downs in the filter for the column. In the case the usage of settings like below

```
stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":All;true:Yes;false:No" }
```

will be very practical. By the way you can use `value` in the object form

```
value: {"": "All", true:"Yes", false: "No"}
```

In other cases if you have small number of values you can use `value` to implement dropdowns in the searching filter.

The usage of `dataUrl` one should use if the list of the values you get dynamically from the database. I can address you to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877286/315935) which explains the main idea of the corresponding implementation.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329014/315935) shows simple pure JavaScript code which demonstrate how one can implements selects and autocomplete on the client side only. In case of server side paging and filtering one should choose another implementation way. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392816/315935) shows how one can implement jQuery UI Autocomplete in ASP.NET MVC solution.

I think that jQuery UI Autocomplete could be good alternative to select in some cases, especially if the number of possible options is very large.

**UPDATED**: There are many ways to make searching case insensitive. In case of usage *local* searching (usage `datatype` other as `"json"` or `xml"` or usage of `loadonce: true`) one should just use `ignoreCase: true` option of jqGrid. In case of *server side* searching you should make searching insensitive *on the server side*. I use personally just [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) during filtering. For example instead of constructs like

```sql
WHERE Name LIKE ('%' + @s + '%')
```

I use

```sql
WHERE Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE ('%' + @s + '%')
```

One more small remarks about the code which you posted:

- use **always** `gridview: true` option. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) for more details.
- specify the pager always in the form `pager: "#jqgPagerFileInfoList"` instead of the form `pager: $("#jqgPagerFileInfoList")`.
- don't use non-existing options like `refresh: true`
- I recommend you to use `autoencode: true` option to force interpret the data returned from the server as text and not as HTML fragments. Without the options you could have problems to display textes having `<`, `&` etc.
- I recommend you examine default values of `colModel` properties (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)). you will see that you can remove from your code `align: 'left'`, `sorttype: 'text'`, `search: true` etc.
- You should use permitted vales for properties of `colModel`. For example `width: '100%'` is incorrect and will be interpreted as default value `width: 150`.
- all values which you use for `jsonmap` are the same as the value of `name` property. So you can remove the values.
- I recommend you remove hidden column `name: 'Id'`. jqGrid use `id` attribute of `<tr>` which represent rows of grid. You use `repeatitems: false` inside of `jsonReader`. You can add in `jsonReader` the property `id: "Id"` to specify that jqGrid should use `"Id"` property of items from the row data for rowids.

Comment: Wow...awesome answer, I'll start implementing this.