# Disable case sensitive with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, case-sensitive

I have a doubt about jQuery autocomplete. When I write something in the field like "LI" I need autocomplete returns all the words that starts with "LI" (the words that is in lowercase and uppercase). But when I write this, autocomplete just returns me the words that are in uppercase. Is it possible to change this?

**UPDATE:** I found a way, I don't know if this is the right way but... I'm using it. It just put in "SELECT" of autocomplete "ILIKE", instead of "LIKE". It works for me, but (again) I don't know if it's the right way to do it!

Comment: Do you have a local or remote data source?

Comment: @mzs_newbie: I personally use [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) inside of `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` to force case sensitive column/table be interpreted as case insensitive.

Comment: @mzs_newbie: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14610656/315935) for code example. Which database you use? Supports it `COLLATE` inside of SELECTs? Alternatively you can add `LOWER` or `UPPER` functions on both sides of compare operation.

Comment: I'm using postgres. Thanks again, I think is better to do what you said! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you build your list for your Autocomplete, this may be automatically built in, for example case does not matter for me in my C# code with Entity frameworks going against a MySQL db.

```
//Builds a search list for Card Name Search boxes
public JsonResult GetACResults(string term) 
{
    return Json((from item in db.tableName
        where item.NameOfInterest.Contains(term)
        select new
        {
            value = item.NameOfInterest
        }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.value).ToList(),
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
} //public JsonResult GetACResults(string term)
```

If this is somthign you have to handle yourself you can look at this post as a solution:
[Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Comment: Hummm ok. It's that I'm using php and I don't know how to this in php. But thanks for that @Mark :)

Comment: The concept should be the same, basically `Contains` is the C# equivalent to `LIKE` in MySQL.  I doubt you will have much trouble finding example(s) of searching for db results that using the `LIKE` with PHP.  Please mark correct if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What about the simplest solution?
My solution is in PHP+MySQL, but you can simply adapt it to every scenario you want.

```
$upperString = strtoupper($stringToCompare);
$query .= "SELECT blablabla WHERE UPPER(columnName) LIKE '%$upperString%'";
```

Works like a charm

Linuxatico

Answer (score -1):

I found a way, I don't know if this is the right way but... I'm using it.
It just put in "SELECT" of autocomplete **"ILIKE"**, instead of **"LIKE"**. It works for me, but (again) I don't know if it's the right way to do it!

:)

Comment: What are you using as the source of your autocomplete? Am I missing something but jqGrid doesn't do autocomplete but you are calling the jQuery autocomplete?

Comment: I'm sorry @Mark... maybe I'm just confused about this... I think is jQuery autocomplete... I will change the title of the question. Thanks for your comment!