# Datainit is giving null

Tags: jqgrid

Can somebody please help me understand why the dataInit function wouldn't have a value for the field. I have the following added to the categories column in my grid.

```
dataInit: function (elem) 
{
var v = $(elem).val(); 
alert("In data init val is " + v);
 $(elem).trigger('change');
}
```

I get a null value in the alert and the trigger function doesn't fire either.

Comment: Could you modify your question and add more full code of the grid? Is `dataInit` are used inside of `searchoptions` or inside of `editoptions`? Which editing mode (form editing, inline editing or cell editing) of which kind of searching (searching toolbar or advanced searching) you use?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem too. In order to accomplish this: [jqgrid incorrect select drop down option values in edit box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469650/jqgrid-incorrect-select-drop-down-option-values-in-edit-box/4480184#4480184) in dataInit and `dataEvents v = $(elem).val();`  and `var v = parseInt($(e.target).val(), 10);` give me back null. If i put in v the right values all the other works fine!

Answer (score 1):

If this question about `editoptions` and using server data. I have got the answer. This is happen because your data is not local but from server. Using server(not local data), browser need several time to load into the select element and change to the selected option as in row.

So, the `$(elem).val();`  from dataInit is null because it is still null on that time, u have to wait about  100 ms(on my case).

Here my code, the case is about loading provinces with its cities on  .

```
dataInit: function (elem) {
    $(elem).ready(loadCities);
},
```

I create function `loadCities` function out of jqgrid definition

```
function loadCities() {
    setTimeout('$.ajax({type: "GET",data: "",   url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/cities/cities_select_options_by_prov_and_store/"+$("#province").val()+"/"+$("#id").val(), success: function(data){  $("#city").html(data);}})',100);
}
```

here are my complete code

```
var gridStores = jQuery('#gridStores');
function loadCities() {
    setTimeout('$.ajax({type: "GET",data: "",   url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/cities/cities_select_options_by_prov_and_store/"+$("#province").val()+"/"+$("#id").val(), success: function(data){  $("#city").html(data);}})',100);
}
var resetCitiesValues = function () {
                gridStores.setColProp('#city', { editoptions: { value: ':- Choose Province First -'} });
            };
gridStores.jqGrid({
    url:'<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/stores/stores_json',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames:['ID','Name'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'stores.id', hidden:true,editable:true},
        {name:'province',index: 'provinces.name', width:100,stype:'text',sorttype:'text',editable:true,editrules:{required:true},edittype:"select",editoptions:{dataUrl:'<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/provinces/provinces_select_options',
                dataInit: function (elem) {
                    $(elem).ready(loadCities);
                },
                dataEvents: [{type: 'change',fn: function(e) {$.ajax({type: "GET",data: "", url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/cities/cities_select_options/"+$(this).val(), success: function(data){  $("#city").html(data);}})}}]}},
        {name:'city',index: 'cities.name', width:100,stype:'text',sorttype:'text',editable:true,editrules:{required:true},edittype:"select", editoptions:{ value: ':- Choose Province First -', defaultValue:'- Choose City -'}},
    ],
    width:'600',
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 40,
    rowNum:10,
    rowList : [20,30,50],
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: '#pagerStores',
    sortname: 'stores.id',
    sortorder: "desc",
    searchOn:"false",
    editurl: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/stores/edit"

});
jQuery("#gridStores").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerStores',
    {
        edit:true,
        add:true,
        del:true,
        search:false,
        refresh:true,
        recreateForm:true, 
        viewPagerButtons:false
    },
    {
        closeAfterEdit:true,
        closeAfterAdd:true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
        editData: {<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>'},
        recreateForm:true, 
        viewPagerButtons:false
    },
    {
        closeAfterEdit:true,
        closeAfterAdd:true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
        editData: {<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>'}
    }, 
    {

        delData: {<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>'},
    }, 
    {
        caption: "Search",
        Find: "Find",
        Reset: "Reset",
        sopt  : ['eq', 'cn'],
        matchText: " match",
        rulesText: " rules",
        stringResult: true
    }
);
jQuery("#gridStores").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
```

Answer (score 0):

The elem is now already an object, so JQuery is not needed to get its properties.

Just use `var v = elem.value`;