# jqgrid form editing editoptions select ajax add parameter

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

i'm trying to build a select element in the form editing jqgrid by calling an ajax webmethod (asp.net).

Everythings work great if I call a method without parameter. It doesn't work if I try to call a webmethod expecting a string parameter:

this is an extract of the code:

```
ajaxSelectOptions: { type: "POST", contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', },
colNames: ['City', 'State'],
colModel: [
{ 
    name: 'City', 
    index: 'City', 
    align: "center", 
    width: 80, 
    searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']} ,
    edittype: 'select',
    editable: true, 
    editrules: { required: true },
    editoptions: { 
        dataUrl: '<%# ResolveUrl("~/Service/Domain/ServiceGeographic.asmx/GetCityByState") %>',
        buildSelect: function (data) {
        var retValue = $.parseJSON(data);
        var response = $.parseJSON(retValue.d);

        var s = '<select id="customer_City" name="customer_City">';

        if (response && response.length) {
            for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
            s += '<option value="' + response[i]["Id"] + '">' + response[i]["Descrizione"] + '</option>';
            }
        }

        return s + "</select>";
        }                        
    }
},
...
```

where can i set the parameter to send to the GetCityByState webmethod?

**EDIT**: I did not highlight that I'm using POST to call webmethod. Even if i tried as [Oleg suggested on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469650/jqgrid-incorrect-select-drop-down-option-values-in-edit-box/4480184#4480184), it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [ajaxSelectOptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) parameter of jqGrid. For example if you need to have the id of the selected row as an additional `id` parameter sent to webmethod identified by `dataUrl` you can use `data` parameter of `ajaxSelectOptions` in function form:

```
ajaxSelectOptions: {
    type: "GET", // one need allows GET in the webmethod (UseHttpGet = true)
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    data: {
        id: function () {
            return JSON.stringify($("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'));
        }
    }
}
```

because in the code above the parameter `dataType: "json"` are used you should modify the first line of `buildSelect` from

```
buildSelect: function (data) {
    var retValue = $.parseJSON(data);
    var response = $.parseJSON(retValue.d);
    ...
```

to

```
buildSelect: function (data) {
    var response = $.parseJSON(data.d);
    ...
```

Moreover because you use the line `$.parseJSON(data.d)` I can suppose that you return the data from the webmethod in the wrong way. Typically the type of return value from the webmethod should be *class*. You should don't include any call of manual serialization of the returned object. Instead of that some people misunderstand that and declare `string` as the return type of the webmethod. They makes JSON serialization manually with call of `DataContractJsonSerializer` or `JavaScriptSerializer`. As the result the manual serialized data returned as string will be one more time serialized. It's the reason why you can have **two** calls of `$.parseJSON`: `var retValue = $.parseJSON(data); var response = $.parseJSON(retValue.d);`. If you will be use `dataType: "json"` inside of `ajaxSelectOptions` and if you would do **no manual serialization to JSON** in web method and just rejurn the object like it be, you would need to have **no** call of `$.parseJSON` at all. You can just use directly `data.d`:

```
buildSelect: function (data) {
    var response = data.d;
    ...
```

Comment: thx oleg, i should send u a gift for last days answers through stackoverflow ;) anyway, first of all you should use : after data (for users who can take an advantage from this topic). Error changed, it became "invalid json primitive". i solve this [static for this time] way data: "{ 'selectedValue': 'value' }"

Comment: @frabiacca: I reread carefully what you wrote about the error. I think that my suggestion should be corrected to use `JSON.stringify()`. In case if you use `type: "POST"` inside of `ajaxSelectOptions` one have to use `data: JSON.stringify({ selectedValue: 'value' })`. It's not comfortable because you can't use function. If you would use and use `UseHttpGet = true` option in the webmethod you will be able to use `data` in the form: `data: { selectedValue: function () { return JSON.stringify($("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')); }`

Comment: @Oleg Can I directly bind  '<select><option>....</option></select>' string to column without any ajax call.

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr: Yes, of cause. You need just use `edittype: "select"` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#edittype))

Comment: @Oleg But in this case also I have to set key value pair to value attribut right? `editoptions: {
                        value: serviceKeyValuePair......`

Comment: @Oleg I face some some problem in case of keyvaluepair  when data contains ';' (semi colon) - some options will show as undefined.

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr: It's better that you post more detailes. The value like `serviceKeyValuePair` gives no information. An example of `editoptions.value` is better. One can specify the `value` in different formats. One can use `separator` and `delimiter` additionally if you use string value of `value`. The default value of `separator` is `":"` and the default value of `delimiter` is `";"`. It could be important to know which evrsion of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: @Oleg I use jqGrid 4.13.5-pre , `serviceKeyValuePair` is just a key-value pair default value of `separator` is `":"` and the default value of delimiter is `";"`, it would be a problem when when  'value` in `key-value pair` contain characters  `":"` and `";"`.

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr: jqGrid supports **multiple formats** of `editoptions.value`. It was the reason why I asked you to include *an example* of data. For example one can use `editoptions: { value: {test: "a;:t", value1: "{[;: 7"}}`. In other words one can use key-value pairs as object with specified properties. Disadvantage of the format: the order of options can be different in different web bvrowsers. If you prefer *string* format then you can use `separator` and `delimiter`, which I described in my last comment. For eyample, `editoptions: { value: "1:2@t1%1;2@t2", delimiter: "%", separator: "@"}`.

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr: It's importan to specify the version of jqGrid so that I could reproduce the problem with *the version*. Every released versions (4.13.4, 4.13.5 and so on) can be easy loaded from [CDN](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) or one can load *the specific* version from GitHub (see [releases](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/releases)). jqGrid 4.13.5-pre is just **some version** between 4.13.4 and 4.13.5. I place the date of the snapshort see the top of the code. Please, upgrade to the last **release** 4.13.5 or use the latest code.

Comment: @Oleg  `delimiter: "%", separator: "@"` won't solve the problem if data contains characters `"%"` and `"@"`, Instead of key-value pair, Can I bind dropdown datasource with json or `<select></select>` string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130582/discussion-between-shamseer-k-smr-and-oleg).

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr: You should use **any** value as `delimiter` and `separator`, which not exist in text/values of the options of the select.