# jqgrid multiselect dropdown when using form edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This is the code of my multiselect dropdown column. It is working as I expected but I want some modification on edit mode.

```
{
    name: 'SubjectId',
    index: 'SubjectId',
    align: 'center',
    hidden: true,
    viewable: true,
    editrules: { edithidden: true },
    editable: true,
    formatter: 'select',
    editable: true,
    edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: {
        multiselect: true,
        dataUrl: '@Url.Action("getAllSubjects", "Subject")',
        //buildSelect: function (data) {
        //var retValue = $.parseJSON(data);
        buildSelect: function (data) {
            var response, s = '<select>', i;
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            // s += '<option value="0">--Select Subject--</option>';
            if (response && response.length) {
                $.each(response, function (i) {
                    s += '<option value="' + this.Id + '">' + this.SubjectName + '</option>';
                });
            }
            return s + '</select>';
        },

        dataInit: function (elem) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#SubjectId').multiselect();
            }, 5);

        },
        multiple: true,
    }
},
```

But on edit mode I want to make multiselect false.How can do it.I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code has typing error: one should use `dataInit` instead of `ddataInit`.

If you need to use `multiselect` only in Add form and not in Edit form I would recommend you better don't use `multiselect: true` and `dataInit`. Instead of that you can use `beforeShowForm` callback (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events)). Inside of the callback you can set `multiple` attribute (see [jQuery.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)) and call `$('#SubjectId').multiselect();`. If you would specify such `beforeShowForm` callback only for the Add form you should have the behavior which you require. Of case you should use `recreateForm: true` [property](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) for both Add and Edit forms.

Comment: in add option I used below but not working as expected      {
                recreateForm: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                beforeShowForm: function () {
                   $.attr($('#SubjectId').multiselect()
               )

Comment: @janina: 1) you should set `multiple` attribute of `$('#SubjectId').attr("multiple", "multiple");`. The code `$.attr($('#SubjectId').multiselect() ) ` is definitively wrong. 2) You use `buildSelect`. So the call of `$('#SubjectId').multiselect();` should be inside of `setTimeout` and all inside of `beforeShowForm`.