# how to use primary key with jqGrid and jsonReader

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jsonreader

I've looked at several posts but don't understand how to use `jsonReader`. I would like to keep my primary key hidden when editing, adding. If I make my permissionID `editable:false` or hidden it wont edit.

Any help or direction to other posts would be great and very appreciated. thanks

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {   
        $("#list").jqGrid(
        {
            url:'Users2.cfc?method=getUsers', //CFC that will return the users
            datatype: 'json', //We specify that the datatype we will be using will be JSON
            colNames:['Bill To Code','User ID', 'GL_comp_key', 'Branch ID', 'Warehouse ID', 'Final Approver',  'Active', 'Primary Approver', 'Administrative','Secondary Approver','permissionID'], //Column Names
            //The Column Model to define the data. Note you can make columns non sortable, specify width, alignment, etc.
            colModel :[
                {name:'ar_bill_key',index:'ar_bill_key', width:125, sorttype:"text",editable:true,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','cn']},
                    editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions:{size:50},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}},
                {name:'userID',index:'userID', width:125, align:"left",sorttype:"text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','ew','cn']},
                    editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions:{size:50},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}},
                {name:'gl_cmp_key',index:'gl_cmp_key', width:125, align:"left",sorttype:"text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','ew','cn']},
                    editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions:{size:50},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}},
                {name:'so_brnch_key',index:'so_brnch_key', width:125, align:"left",sorttype:"text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','ew','cn']},
                    editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions:{size:50},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}},
                {name:'so_whs_key',index:'so_whs_key', width:125,align:"left",sorttype:"text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','ew','cn']},
                    editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions:{size:50},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}},
                {name:'final_approver',index:'final_approver', width:125,align:"left",sorttype:"text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','ew','cn']},
                    editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"1:Yes;0:No"},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}},  
                {name:'active',index:'active', width:125,align:"left",sorttype:"text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','ew','cn']},
                    editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"1:Yes;0:No"},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}},
                {name:'primary_approver',index:'primary_approver', width:125,align:"left",sorttype:"text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','ew','cn']},
                    editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"1:Yes;0:No"},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}},  
                {name:'admin',index:'admin', width:125,align:"left",sorttype:"text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','ew','cn']},
                    editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"1:Yes;0:No"},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}},  
                {name:'secondary_approver',index:'secondary_approver', width:130,align:"left",sorttype:"text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','ew','cn']},
                    editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"1:Yes;0:No"},editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}},
                {name:'permissionID',index:'permissionID',sorttype:"int",editable:true,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','lt','le','gt','ge']}},
            ],//searchoptions parameter is used to limit the operators available during search
            pager: $('#pager'), //The div we have specified, tells jqGrid where to put the pager
            rowNum:20, //Number of records we want to show per page
            rowList:[20,30,40,50], //Row List, to allow user to select how many rows they want to see per page
            sortorder: "desc", //Default sort order
            sortname: "ar_bill_key", //Default sort column
            viewrecords: true, //Shows the nice message on the pager
            imgpath: '/images', //Image path for prev/next etc images
            caption: 'Permissions', //Grid Name
            recordtext: "Record {0} - {1} of {2}",//Pager information to show
            rownumbers: true,//Show row numbers
            rownumWidth: "30",//Width of the row numbers column
            sortable: true,
            height:'auto', //I like auto, so there is no blank space between. Using a fixed height can mean either a scrollbar or a blank space before the pager
            mtype:'POST',   
            toolbar:[true,"top"], //Shows the toolbar at the top. We will use it to display user feedback
            //The JSON reader. This defines what the JSON data returned from the CFC should look like
            jsonReader: {
                root: "ROWS", //our data
                page: "PAGE", //current page
                total: "TOTAL", //total pages
                records:"RECORDS", //total records
                userdata:"USERDATA", //Userdata we will pass back for feedback
                cell: "", //Not Used
                ar_bill_key: "0" //Will default to first column
                },
            editurl:"Users2.cfc?method=addeditUser" //The Add/Edit function call                
            }               
        ).navGrid('#pager',
            {
                search:true,searchtitle:"Search",//title set for hover over display
                edit:true,edittitle:"Edit User",
                add:true,addtitle:"Add User",
                del:false,deltitle:"Delete User"
            },
        // Edit Options. savekey parameter will keybind the Enter key to submit.
        {editCaption:"Edit User",edittext:"Edit",closeOnEscape:true, savekey: [true,13],errorTextFormat:commonError
            ,reloadAfterSubmit:true,bottominfo:"Fields marked with (*) are required",top:"60",left:"70",width:500}, 
        {width:500,addCaption:"Add User",edittext:"Add",closeOnEscape:true,savekey: [true,13],errorTextFormat:commonError,
            reloadAfterSubmit:true,bottominfo:"Fields marked with (*) are required",top:"60",left:"70"}, //Add Options
        {url:"Users2.cfc?method=delUser",caption:"Delete User",closeOnEscape:true,errorTextFormat:commonError,top:"60",left:"70",
            reloadAfterSubmit:true}, //Delete Options
         //Search Options. multipleSearch parameter lets it know we are going to use the new advanced search feature
        {errorTextFormat:commonError,Find:"Search",closeOnEscape:true,caption:"Search Users",multipleSearch:true,closeAfterSearch:true}
        );          

        //Function will be called when add/edit encounters an error. The returned message is what will be shown to user 
        function commonError(data)
        {           
            return "Error Occured during Operation. Please try again";
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: Oleg, thanks for your response. I want to have the permissionid hidden at all times. I found a way that seems to work. What do you think of this?  {name:'permissionID',index:'permissionID',sorttype:"int",hidden:true,editable:true,resizable:false,editrules:{readonly:true}},   Also how do I display the message usaer added in a div on the grid header?  Thanks very much!! Your posts are great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct your question you want just that `permissionID` will be send during editing, but you not need to display it somewhere.

I suppose, that your original problem that you don't specify which id should has the rows of the grid. The JSON input should contain the `id`. If you use `cell: ""` setting in the `jsonReader` you have to specify the id of the row in one from the two ways:

- you included `key: true` property in the definition of the column `'permissionID'`. In the case you don't need to mark the column editable (you can remove `editable:true`).
- if you never need to display to the user the column `'permissionID'` you can **remove** column `'permissionID'` and just include in the `jsonReader` the property `id: "10"`. If I calculated correct you placed the primary key `permissionID` as the 10-th position. In the case the value of `permissionID` will be saved only as the `id` of the rows (`<tr>` elements) of the grid. The `id` will be always send in all edit operations.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the edit to work if I don't pass the primary key permissionID in because I have                           WHERE
      permissionID = #Val(Arguments.permissionID)#   in my update query.

Comment: Hurray!! I used your suggestion of ID ="10" I finally figured out what that meant and arranged my query to match it. Thanks very very much When I am allowed to give you votes I will do it!!

Comment: @Sue: One more advice: you should remove `imgpath` option which is deprecated (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options)). You can consider to use `formatter: "checkbox", edittype: "checkbox"` which can reduce the total width of the grid. You can remove all default properties (like `align:"left",sorttype:"text"`). I recommend you also to use column templates (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)). It can reduce the size of the JavaScript code and improve it readability and manageability.

Comment: Hi Oleg,I have posted a question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506231/jqgrid-dependent-selects-for-edit-form-with-coldfusion-cfc

Comment: @Sue: I have no examples where one uses `dataUrl` together with dependent selects, but it should be implemented in the same way like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935).

Comment: Hi Oleg,I have posted a question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506231/jqgrid-dependent-selects-for-edit-form-with-coldfusion-cfc  I am trying to use dataUrl to set up 3 selects, 1st select a value and the next 2 can be selected based on a query to the database using the first ID. I have tried to set up build select and a change function from the documents but I canot get ny data to display. The data is there in firebug like this:{"COLUMNS":["SO_WHS_KEY"],"DATA":[["WC01"],["WC02"],["WCAC"], I know something is wrong with columns vs rows can you suggest where is the docs on this.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am trying to use your example.

Comment: @Sue: I read your question before, but it's written too unclear. You wrote about 3 selects, but included in the code only one. You included a lot of absolutely unneeded information like `commonSubmit` function which you never use, many column and so on. I don't understand which relevance has how you fill the grid (JSON data) with the way how you edit it. I can only you recommend carefully read and debug the demo from [my old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935). I think it should help you to solve your main problem with dependent selects.

Comment: Thanks very much, I am going through your example line by line now and setting it up with my data. I really need more training and knowledge before doing this but it's for work so I have to find a way.