# jqGrid select editOptions are not updated immediately

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to dynamically load values into a select in a jqGrid. It almost works. The problem is that the values that are returned from the server, are not displayed until the user change row! When I debug, I can see the correc values are being set, but the selection list does not update! Using IE9.

```
        $("#my_grid").setColProp("master_col", { editoptions: { value: data.verksamheter, dataEvents:
        [
            { type: 'change', fn: function (e) {
                var url = '@Url.Action("GetData", "Controller")'
                $.getJSON(url, { id: e.srcElement.value }, function (data) {
                    $("#my_grid").setColProp("details_col", { editoptions: { value: data.verksamhetsslag} });

                });

            } 
            }
        ]
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to update the select list of one column ("details_col") *during the editing is already started*, for example if you need update the select list of the column "details_col" is the user changes the option in select of another column ("master_col"), you have to do this **manually**. Just setting of new `value` of `editoptions` is not enough.

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935) I demonstrated how to do this. The code is not short, but the steps are really required.