# Using jqGrid, Is there anyway to have dynamic dropdown in the edit record popup?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a record that has three fields and they are all dropdowns.  It all works fine if they are independent records but i would like it where if you change the first dropdown, then the list of items in the second dropdown changes?  Is this possible in jqgrid.

Simplified version of my code looks like this now:

```
jQuery("#marketDataGrid").jqGrid({
    mtype: "POST",
    url: "/Application/MarketData/" + id,
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ["", "Id","Source", "API"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "ApplicationId", index: "ApplicationId", hidden: true, width: 0, editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: true} },
        { name: "Id", index: "Id", hidden: false, width: 30, editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true} },
        { name: "MarketDataSource", index: "MarketDataSource", editoptions: { dataUrl: "/MarketDataSource/GetSelectDataRequired" }, editrules: { required: true }, editable: true, edittype: "select", width: 155, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], dataUrl: "/MarketDataSource/GetSelectData"} },
        { name: "API", index: "API", editoptions: { dataUrl: "/API/GetSelectDataRequired" }, editrules: { required: true }, editable: true, edittype: "select", width: 155, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], dataUrl: "/API/GetSelectData"} }

    ],
```

Comment: I suppose you want something like this http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects1.htm ?

Comment: double click on country column of any row, change the value, states value get changed

Comment: @PiyushSardana - thanks . . i am trying to do this not inline in the grid but rather on the popup edit form.  Is a similar thing possible?

Comment: I'm sure that it'll work on form editing also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no simple way to implement dependent selects in jqGrid. Nevertheless I shown in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/editwithdependendselects2.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935) how dependent selects could be implemented. I demonstrated the implementation in tree cases: inline editing, form editing and searching toolbar.

In your case you use `dataUrl` of `editoptions` instead of `value` used in the referenced demo. Nevertheless the implementation can be based on the same idea. You can register `change` event for the "main" select and make `$.ajax` request to the server to get the subset of select's options of the dependent select. Inside of `success` handle of `$.ajax` you will be able to do the same thing like in my demo.