# JQGrid: Can't get Row ID in DataInit function

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Ok I came back to this, I just removed the formatter: "select", which was requiring a matched state key to display in the grid.

---

Ok I give up, my solution is:

search: false, editable: false

until the new version of JQGrid.

---

Ok, so looking at Oleg's code, it seems the solution there is to initially populate the state select with every possible value for all countries.   Given that there are quite a few "states" (worldwide) that I deal with, it's a bit kludgy to pull down 3-4000 states just to find a match to the actual cell value. Still working on this.

---

I have dependent country and state dropdowns (both toolbar search, inline edit, and form edit).  I am having a problem getting the row id in the datainit function, so that I can retrieve the country value from the datainit function of the state searchoptions/editoptions.

Surely there's a way to retrieve this?  I tried setting a timeout as well, no luck:

```
    { name: "State", index: "MYSTATE", width: 50, align: "left", editable: true, formatter: "select", stype: "select", edittype: "select", sortable: true, editrules: { required: true, custom: true, custom_func: validateState },
            searchoptions:
            {
                value: GetStates('NG', true), // just hardcoded here for now
                dataInit: function (elem)
                {
                    var rowId = $(elem.target).closest('tr.jqgrow').attr('id');
                    var country = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'Country');
```

...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code can't work because the callback `dataInit` will be called **before** the new `<select>` or `<input>` element are placed on the page. Moreover `elem.target` is wrong. Even `$(elem).closest('tr.jqgrow')` will be always empty jQuery element. To be exact the code will be do possible if you would use the newest code of jqGrid from [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid). The reason is [the resent changes](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/08ba34b0b53834b7328f6667f0cdbe9b777a513b) which are made base on [my suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/calling-of-datainit-and-dataevents-after-the-control-are-placed-on-the-page/#p27265). If you use the last released version of jqGrid 4.4.1 the changes are still not here. I think that one should make some additional changes in the code of jqGrid to make implementation of dependent selects more easy.

I find the implementation of dependent selects very complex and tricky. I would recommend you to examine [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditWithDependendSelects2_.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935).

Comment: Thanks for your response Oleg.  I do have the dependent dropdowns working, using your code as a reference.  The only problem is the initial condition, where I need the value of the country dropdown to populate the state dropdown.  I tried the version from github and I'm not clear on what I need to do.  I did notice that it broke the implementation of the filament group daterangepicker that I was using on the search toolbar.