# jqgrid: change value of select

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, jqgrid

I am developing a web application using JSP & Servlet (IDE: Eclipse, Database: Oracle10). I am using `jqGrid` to display records in tabular format.

**code snippet:**

```
{name:'CITY',index:'CITY', width:70,editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions: {dataUrl: 'ProfileServ?action=comboCity', dataEvents: [{  type: 'change', fn: function(e) {alert(this.value);city= this.value;}}],}}, 
{name:'PIN',index:'PIN', width:200,sortable:false,editable:true, edittype:"select",editoptions: {dataUrl: 'ProfileServ?action=comboPin'}},
```

I want to change values of `PIN` according to the value selected in `CITY`. I have used `dataEvents` and `type: 'change'` to get the selected value of `CITY`. I am successfully getting the selected value of `CITY`.

My question is that how should I update the values of `PIN` when value of `CITY` is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to implement dependent selects. One have to update the whole `<select>` of dependent select **manually** inside of `change` callback (update selects of PIN in your case). The only which I can suggest you is examining the code of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditWithDependendSelects2_.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935). It is not exactly what you need because it don't use `dataUrl`, but it shows what should be done.

Comment: +1 for answering(and Thanks again), I read most of your answers related to this question before asking this question, and I had already seen your demo, but still before asking this question I thought that there might be a way in `jqgrid` to accomplish this task. now I think I have to change my code according to your `demo` and `answers`.