# I want to add load event in editoption of jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to add load event in editoption of jqGrid.

My code is like this:

```
dataEvents: [
{
    type: 'change',
    fn: function (e)
    {
        Myfunction();
    }
},
{
    type: 'load',
    fn: function (e)
    {
        Myfunction();
    }
}]
```

My problem is: The change event is called very well, but the load event is not called.

Comment: Cam you explain when do you want to call the load event and the purpose of the load event

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in which situation you want that the handle of [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) handler will be called. If you use `dataUrl` to load the `<select>` from the server then you can use `buildSelect` as replacement of "load" hendler. If the server returns already HTML fragment with `<select>` the `buildSelect` callbacl can be as following

```js
dataUrl: "mySelectUrl",
buildSelect: function (data) {
    Myfunction();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to use this thing in thae case of two select box in edit form......scene is whene I select A from XYZ select box then the Option of PXR select box are S,Y,U and B from XYZ select box then the Option of PXR select box are K,L,O

Comment: @NisargPatel: You are welcome! Implementation of dependent selects is complex in the current version of jqGrid. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935) which describes how one can do this in case of usage without `dataUrl`. Implementation in case of `dataUrl` will be mostly in the same way.