# jqGrid troubles with chained select lists in form editing

Tags: list, select, jqgrid, dialog, chained

After looking in this forum some way to solve these problems and without success, I hope someone could spend a few time for driving me to understand what happens and how to solve it.

Here is the snapshot of the trouble :

[image]

and the JSON response from server :

```
{"page":"1","total":1017,"records":"20335","rows":[{"id":"10390","cell":["10390",
" MM23398A","***.REVISION NE PAS UTILISER","ECHANGEUR","Echangeurs complets
\u00e0 plaques","","","","","","0","1"]},{"id":"1","cell":["1","\"304010","Joint
arm\u00e9 NE PAS UTILISER voir Z304010","VANNE","Pi\u00e8ces d\u00e9tach\u00e9es 
de vannes","","","","54.00","","0","4"]},{"id":"13583","cell":["13583","#POMPES"
,"Article g\u00e9n\u00e9rique pompes.","POMPE","Pompes centrifuges compl\u00e8tes
PANTHER","","","","","","0","3"]},{"id":"3","cell":["3","#POMPES\/10944\/0001",
"","ECHANGEUR","Echangeurs complets \u00e0 plaques","","","","","","0","1"]},
{"id":"4","cell":["4","#POMPES\/10944\/0002","","ECHANGEUR","Echangeurs complets 
\u00e0 plaques","","","","","","0","1"]},{"id":"5","cell":["5","#POMPES\/10971
\/0003","Article g\u00e9n\u00e9rique pompes","POMPE","Pompes centrifuges compl
\u00e8tes PANTHER","","","","","","0","3"]}
```

(the last cell is the above selected row)

As you can see, the informations in the selected row and the edit form ('S/famille') are not similar !
That's because the second list box is not populated with the good items, depending of the first list box.

How can I initialize this list with good items ? I have tried several ways without success, according some posts on forum.

**UPDATED 2013-04-05**

First of all, the colModels of these list boxes :

```
            {name:'fam',index:'f.code', width:80,
            formoptions:{
                elmprefix:"<span style='visibility:hidden;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;(<span style='color:red;'>*</span>)&nbsp;</span>"
            },
            editable:true,
            edittype:'select',
            editoptions:{
                dataUrl:'selfam.php',
                dataEvents: [
                    {
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function(e) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url:'selsfm.php?id='+$(e.target).val(),
                                async:false,
                                mType:'GET',
                                success:function(data){
                                    $("#tr_sfm select.FormElement").html(data);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {name:'sfm',index:'s.code', width:80,
            formoptions:{
                elmprefix:"<span style='visibility:hidden;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;(<span style='color:red;'>*</span>)&nbsp;</span>"
            },
            editable:true,
            edittype:'select',
            cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                return ' title="'+rawObject[13]+'"';
            }
        },
```

and the code for editing buttons, I take id from rowdata for initially loading second list box, and id from prev/next row when clicking on nav buttons :

```
    myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#tab21p',{search:false,del:false}, 
    { // edit options
        width:500,
        modal:true,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        recreateForm: true,
        editCaption:"Modifier un ARTICLE",
        onInitializeForm: function(form) {
            rowdata = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',selectedId);
            id_fam=rowdata['fam_id'];
            id_sfm=rowdata['sfm_id'];
            $.ajax({
                url:'selsfm.php?id='+id_fam+'&edit',
                async:false,
                mType:'GET',
                success:function(data){
                    $("#tr_sfm select.FormElement").html(data);
                    $("#tr_sfm select.FormElement").val(id_sfm);
                }
            });
        },
        onclickPgButtons : function (whichbutton, formid, rowid) {
            var row = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
            if(whichbutton=='next'){row+=1;}else{row-=1;}
            rowdata = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',row);
            id_fam=rowdata['fam_id'];
            id_sfm=rowdata['sfm_id'];
        } 
    },
    {    // add options
        width:500,
        modal:true,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        recreateForm: true,
        addCaption:"Créer un ARTICLE",
        onInitializeForm: function(form) {
            id_fam=1;
            id_sfm=1;
            $.ajax({
                url:'selsfm.php?id='+id_fam+'&add',
                async:false,
                mType:'GET',
                success:function(data){
                    $("#tr_sfm select.FormElement").html(data);
                    $("#tr_sfm select.FormElement").val(id_sfm);
                }
            });
    },
    {}, //del options
    {} //search options
);
```

and finally, when selecting a row from the main grid, I take ids from rowdata for loading second list :

```
    onSelectRow:function(id,status){
        selectedId=id;
        rowdata = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',id);
        id_fam=rowdata['fam_id'];
        id_sfm=rowdata['sfm_id'];
        $.ajax({
            url:'selsfm.php?id='+id_fam+'&select',
            async:false,
            mType:'GET',
            success:function(data){
                $("#tr_sfm select.FormElement").html(data);
                $("#tr_sfm select.FormElement").val(id_sfm);
            }
        });
    },
```

Oleg, please if you have a few time to have a look, many many thanks to tell me remarks about this code, so I could be less newbie ! Thanks again for sharing your experience. Have a nice day. JiheL

**UPDATED 2013-04-08**

I have applied some of Oleg's comments, that let me to obtain a clearer code. Many thanks Oleg, I greatly appreciate to be driven with your experience. I'm loving more and more jqGrid because you.

1. About 'dataEvents', I don't understand why you tell me to use this, with e.target. I've seen it can be used in editoptions but I don't know what you mean.
2. The variable 'selectedId' is used when I'm editing a row and navigate with pgButtons. If I don't memorize the new row id, the second list box is not updated and disparate with first box.
3. A new point, when I valid the form, I see in Firebug all pairs which are posted to server.
   [image]

As you can see, the first element is blank with a value, it seems to me that it is 'sfm', the second list box's colName.
Please have you an idea why this happens and how to solve it ?

I hope not to bother you with these continous questions. I don't find any book that could give me some knowledge about coding jqGrid. I hope that nearly this could exist.
Thanks in advance for spend time. Have a nice day. JiheL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqGrid don't contains any built-in support of dependent selects.

If you really need implement dependent selects based I can you forward to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935). It shows how to change *manually* the content of the second (dependent) select based on changes in the first one.

In generally jqGrid need sure some flexible way how to *refresh* some select based on new parameters (new `dataUrl` for example).

Comment: one more time I have to thank you very much for your kind help and the way you drive me to find solution at this problem. As these list boxes are filled from database, I had to change the way, I update my question to submit changes to your agreement. Many time for me is saved, I hope you have not spent too much time with my problem. Have a nice day. JiheL

Comment: @user2132268: You are welcome! It's difficult to comment the code without debugging it. Some things could be improved: Why `onSelectRow` should make `$.ajax` especially having `async:false` and it try to set data in the form which could not exist? Instead of introducing `selectedId` variable you could use `getGridParam` with `"selrow"`. Instead of usage `myGrid` you can use `$(this)` inside of all callbacks. `dataEvents` works for *all* editing modes. So I recommend you to test whether `e.target` inside of form and execude the code which corresponds the editing mode used.

Comment: @user2132268: Some other common remarks about JavaScript code: You use `rowdata`, `id_fam`, `id_sfm` variables which are declared in outer scope or globally. It's better to declare variables used for temporary purpose *locally* inside of the corresponding function or callback. You should better use `rowdata.fam_id` instead of `rowdata['fam_id']`. I would recommend you to introduce function like `reloadSelect` which makes `$.ajax` and fill the dependent select. You can call it with `$(e.target).val()` or `$(this).jqGrid('getCel',$(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'),'fam_id')` as parameter.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help, many many good things in your comments that I try to apply as closest as possible. I have not all understood, so I update my question to expose the trouble. Many thanks again. JiheL