# jqGrid Drop Down Value

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am working on some project where i need to filter student based on the Degree in grid. I have a drop down where it loads the all degree list from DB, below is the image[image]. But problem is by default it will select the 1st value unlike other drop downs there will be default text like --Please Select-- etc. Is there any way to create something sort of that.I have used map & list to load drop down.Below is what i have done so far. Any help will help me in turn.

```
 colModel : [ {name : 'usn_number',index : 'usn_number',searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'] },width : 20},
                              {name : 'first_name',index : 'first_name',searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'] },width : 35},
                              {name : 'course',index : 'course',width : 20,stype: 'select',searchoptions:{value:getOptionsList(),
                                    sopt:['eq']}},
                              {name : 'semester_name',index : 'semester_name',search:false,width : 20},
                              {name : 'address',index : 'address',search:false,width : 30},
                              {name : 'mobile_number',index : 'mobile_number',search:false,width : 20},
                              {name : 'id',index : 'id',align : "center",sortable : false,search:false,align : 'center',
                                  width : 15,formatter : controlFmatter}
                            ],
```

The function getOptionsList() is defined,

```
function getOptionsList(){
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'loadDegreeList',
    async:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        options=data.degreeListMap;
    },
    failure :function(xhr,status,msg) {
        alert("Unexpected error occured. !!!"+msg);
    }
 });
return options;
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
success: function(data){
        options = "0:--Please Select--";
        for ( var j = 0; j < data.list.length; j++) {//Your List where those values is stored
            var records = data.list[j];
            options += ";"+records.ID+":"+ records.name ;// ID is primary key of that column & name is your degrees list
        }
    }
```

Also [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469650/jqgrid-incorrect-select-drop-down-option-values-in-edit-box) Hope it helped

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer worked for me, but have to make changes in DB like if you select that option it should not search that record.

Answer (score 2):

I am using SpringFramework. I created the List in Controller like this.

```
......
List<Locations> locList = new ArrayList<Locations>();
locList.add(new Locations());      // Add a Blank RecordFirst. You can modify it as you want.
locList.addAll(baseInformationService.getAllLocationsList());  // Add other list records
model.addAttribute("locList", locList);       // put it to the model
......
```

Hope can help you.

Comment: k i will try it out & let you know.