# LinQ to generate statesOfCountry javascript array

Tags: javascript, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, entity-framework-6.1

Finally find in [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469650/jqgrid-incorrect-select-drop-down-option-values-in-edit-box/4480184#4480184) solution how to generate related filter selects for a jqGrid... but now I'm wondering how generate this statesOfCountry JavaScript array in my MVC 4 app using using EF 6.1.

I'm assuming that linq will help to get something like this on my MVC controller:

```
var rel_man_lin =
(
    from f in db.Products
    select new
       {
          f.IdMaufacture,
          line = new [] {
             from l in db.Lines 
             where f.Relation.IdLine == l.IdLine
             select l.IdLine
          }.Single()
       }
).Distinct();
ViewData["rel_fab_lin"] = rel_fab_lin;
```

To finally set on my scripts region on my view this:

```
var ls = [@ViewData["rel_fab_lin"]];
```

It should be like this or exists some other way?

Thanks!

Comment: So what you have done has worked?

Comment: No, at this moment I'm have some alternative to move array data to view... but don't have idea of linq sentence to generate something like this:

    var statesOfCountry = {
        1: { '1': 'Alabama', '2': 'California', '3': 'Florida', '4': 'Hawaii' },
        2: { '5': 'London', '6': 'Oxford' }
    };

Comment: Looks like will need C# jagged array and a way to transfer into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way just an example:

```
        var rel_man_lin= db.Products.GroupJoin(db.Lines,
        p => p.Relation.IdLine,
        l => l.IdLine,
(p, result) => new Result(p.IdMaufacture, result));
```

// Test the Enumerate results to see if it meets your expectation
         foreach (var result in rel_man_lin)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} contains...", result.IdMaufacture);
             foreach (var item in result.ListOfState)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",item.IdofState, item.NameOfstate);
            }
         }
Please note that `.ListOfState, .NameOfstate and IdofState` don't exist but just to express the idea behind the query as you want result to be formatted as an `Id` and a `collection`.

I hope it will help you.