# How to: jqGrid dependent select box display values in rows

Tags: jqgrid

I have implemented dependent dropdowns in jqGrid (similar to this [example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditWithDependendSelects.htm)).  The row data returned has values as well as display values. How can I show display values on grid rows? At grid initialization time I do not have list of values for dependent dropdowns, they get loaded from the server when user selects value from other dropdown. `formatter: 'select'` helps when I know the values of dependent dropdown but I am not sure how to use it when the values are loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In case of loading the data from the server you need just set `editoptions.value` or `formatoptions.value` **before** `formatter: "select"` start to process the data. You can use `beforeProcessing` callback for example. It will be called at the moment which you need. You can place the information with `editoptions.value` in `userdata` part of the server response or in any other place. The `data` parameter (the first parameter) of `beforeProcessing` callback contains *all* the data from the server response. So you can easy get the required data and to use `setColProp` for example to change the options used by `formatter: "select"`. I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) for the corresponding code example.