# JQGrid Change Value Of Cell While Changing Another Cell

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have `jqgrid` with `inline editing mode`. What I want to accomplish is when changing cell value, another cell value to be changed too.

What I have for now is:

```
ondblClickRow: function (id) {
    var selR = $(this).getRowData(id);

    $("#" + $(selR.Inflow).attr("id")).keypress(function () {              
      $(obj.grid).jqGrid("setCell", id, "Inflow", "123321");
 });
}
```

With this try the cell value is changed but edit mode is disabled after invoking `setCell`. I want to change it but to stay in edit mode. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to define `dataEvents` property of `editoptions` of the first column. You can bind `change` event handler which you define inside of `dataEvents`. It allows you to monitor the changing of the first column. To access the second column inside of the `change` event handler you can use `jQuery.val` method, where you use id selector. You need just to know that ids of all fields on inline editing are build based on the rowid (the id of outer `<tr>` element) appended with underscore (`"_"`) and the name on the column. The "UPDATED 3" part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935) provides the demo which do the changes in more common case. To get the rowid from the `Event` object `e` you can use `$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")`.

Comment: Ok i tried it. The difference between the example and my case is that I use  input element type text. After change the value of html inside this element it looks like this 

<input type="text" id="4_Inflow" name="Inflow" role="textbox" class="editable" style="width: 98%;">Value goes here</input>

Despite this the value on the screen stays the same on the same row. Did I miss something ?

Comment: @TheChampp: I wrote in my answer that you should just use `jQuery.val` instead of `jQuery.html`. For example `$("#" + rowid + "_Inflow").val("new Value")`, where `var rowid = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");`